# How to replace QByteArray with std lib?

Tags: c++, qt, std, qbytearray

I want to replace a **QByteArray** with stdlib.
The **QByteArray** is used for append various 'struct' and after that, write it on a file.

How can I replace **QByteArray**? Vector of char? A buffer Char*?

What do you recommend me?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think `std::vector<uint8_t>` is suitable.

This is an example of appending elements from `v2` to the end of `v1`:

```
std::vector<uint8_t> v1 = {1, 2, 3};
std::vector<uint8_t> v2 = {4, 5, 6};

v1.insert(v1.end(), v2.begin(), v2.end());

for (uint8_t val : v1) {
    std::cout << (uint32_t)val << ' ';
}
std::cout << '\n';
```

Output:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6
```